# Git ignore whitelisting all files in a subdirectory, recursively

Tags: git

My software project is modular. Some files are committed by the developer under assigned subdirectories, other are uncompressed to provide an environment runtime (web resources) for development and shall not be committed.

```
- webapp
   - common (provided)
   - error (provided)
   - secure
      - admin (provided)
      - audit (provided)
      - ftt (provided)
   - WEB-INF (to ignore)
```

I want to ignore **everything** under webapp **except** all files under `/webapp/secure/ftt` and its subdirectories.

I tried

```
/webapp
!/webapp/secure/ftt
```

But Git still ignores ftt.

I expect those directories to contain only `.jsp` and `.js` files. But I can't know what happens in the future (e.g. gif, pdf, etc)

How can I tell Git to whitelist files under `/webapp/secure/ftt` and ignore everything else under `/webapp`?

From my research I found it may be impossible without listing each specific subdirectory and file pattern.

[Add] after @DevDonkey comment I tried to empty my entire gitignore file and leave what he posted

```
/webapp/*
!/webapp/secure/ftt
```

Along with plenties of useless files (e.g. .class files) that are now candidate for indexing, because as I said I emptied the gitignore, I find sample.jsp still ignored

[image: See yourself]

Comment: Sounds OK to me, is `!/webapp/secure/ftt` committed or you just added it?

Comment: It's not committed yet, I started a fresh project. But Git doesn't want me to commit ftt

Comment: I use Eclipse as IDE. I expect changes to the gitignore file to be reflected on save (I have workspace auto-refresh enabled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
/webapp/*
!/webapp/secure/ftt
```

works for me locally. Note the addition of the slash and wildcard, so git keeps the root folder, but then processes the rest.

Comment: This works as soon as there are files in the folder committed before gitignore modification

Answer (score 0):

You should follow some inelegant solution like deploying a separate `.gitignore` file to the `/webapp/secure/ftt` directory based on the following:

```
# Ignore any file in this directory except for this file and *.foo files
*
!/.gitignore
!*.foo
```

If you are unwilling or unable to add that .gitignore file, there is an inelegant solution:

```
# Ignore any file but *.foo under Resources. Update this if we add deeper directories
Resources/*
!Resources/*/
!Resources/*.foo
Resources/*/*
!Resources/*/*/
!Resources/*/*.foo
Resources/*/*/*
!Resources/*/*/*/
!Resources/*/*/*.foo
Resources/*/*/*/*
!Resources/*/*/*/*/
!Resources/*/*/*/*.foo
```

Comment: I understand I need a separate gitignore under /webapp/secure/ftt. > Correct?

Comment: Yes. That's great you understood.

Comment: What I don't *understand* is how does the gitignore in /webapp/secure/ftt affect files under /webapp/common, etc. The second inelegant example is clear to me